# Not getting Shiver Me Timbers hat - Winter Bash 2019

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

I got whats needed for Shiver Me Timbers:

> provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an already accepted answer having a score of 2 or more, by at least 2

Here:

[Can I check pandas dataframe index is end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319399/can-i-check-pandas-dataframe-index-is-end/59319414#59319417)

But I didn't get the hat for it.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen in the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59319399/timeline), your answer was posted before the other answer, so you do not accomplish the requirement of posting *after* another answer was already accepted.

Answer (score 1):

After all I got it now, just realized it was phrased:

> provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an already accepted answer having a score of 2 or more, by at least 2

so that means an already accepted answer.